# How to make array of objects in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to send a multi level array via AJAX. so I tried to make an object of objects as follow:

```
var info = {};

info.pickup = {};
info.pickup.contact = {};
info.pickup.items_quantity = {};
info.pickup.items = {};

info.delivery = {};
info.delivery.contact = {};
info.delivery.level = {};
```

then I started filling the objects, for example:

```
$('.operation-create .pickup .contact-details').each(function () {
    var arr = {};
    arr['contact_name'] = $(this).find('input[name="pickup-contact-name"]').val();
    arr['contact_phone'] = $(this).find('input[name="pickup-contact-phone"]').val();
    arr['pickup-suburb'] = $(this).find('select[name="pickup-suburb"]').val();
    arr['single-pickup-address'] = $(this).find('input[name="single-pickup-address"]').val();
    info.pickup.contact.push(arr);
});
info.pickup.push(info.pickup.contact);
```

etc...

However unfortunately it didn't work. I get this error:

> info.pickup.contact.push is not a function

What I should do here? What is the right way to send this array via AJAX?

Comment: Change `contact` to an array: `info.pickup.contact = [];`

Comment: your data structure is a bit unclear, because you use `info.pickup` as array with pushing objects, like `info.pickup.contact` and at the same time, you use it as plain object with custom properties.

Comment: @NinaScholz I am really not good with js objects, that's why I am confused about declaring these arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand the difference between an object and an array.

`{}` creates a plain object, which doesn't have a `push` method.

`[]` creates an array, which is an object with additional features, including a `push` method.

Looking at your code, at the **least**, you want `info.pickup.contact` and probably `info.delivery.contact` to be arrays (I'm guessing probably `items_quantity` and `items` as well, but it's hard to be sure). (The thing you call `arr` in your looping function isn't an array and doesn't need to be.)

So at a minimum:

```
info.pickup.contact = [];
// -------------------^^
```

and

```
info.delivery.contact = [];
// ---------------------^^
```

You also want to remove the `info.pickup.push(info.pickup.contact);` at the end; `info.pickup` isn't an array, and you've already put the contacts in `info.pickup.contact`.

---

Side note: Your code might also benefit from using object initializers:

```
var info = {
    pickup: {
        contact: [],
        items_quantity: {},    // This might also want to be an array
        items: {}              // This might also want to be an array
    },
    delivery: {
        contact: [],
        level: {}              // No idea what you're doing with this, so...
    }
};

$('.operation-create .pickup .contact-details').each(function () {
    info.pickup.contact.push({
        contact_name: $(this).find('input[name="pickup-contact-name"]').val(),
        contact_phone: $(this).find('input[name="pickup-contact-phone"]').val(),
        pickup-suburb: $(this).find('select[name="pickup-suburb"]').val(),
        single-pickup-address: $(this).find('input[name="single-pickup-address"]').val()
    });
});
```

...but it's a matter of style.

Comment: yeah they want to be an array, thanks for explanation

Answer (score 4):

You need an array as value

```
info.delivery.contact = [];
//                      ^^
```

The last line

```
info.pickup.push(info.pickup.contact);
```

makes no sense, because you have properties in this object. For pushing some values, you need an array

```
info.pickup = [];
//            ^^
```

An while you already have an array for `info.pickup.contact`, you could skip the line

> <strike>info.pickup.push(info.pickup.contact);</strike>

Answer (score 3):

```
info.pickup.contact = {};
```

That is an object declaration, not array.

An array should be

```
info.pickup.contact = [];  // `[]`
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have stated you need to change the `contact` from an object (ie. `{}`) to an array (`[]`).

Also note that you can use jQuery's `map()` to build the array and make the code a little more succinct:

```
info.pickup.contact = $('.operation-create .pickup .contact-details').map(function () {
  return {
    contact_name: $(this).find('input[name="pickup-contact-name"]').val(),
    contact_phone: $(this).find('input[name="pickup-contact-phone"]').val(),
    pickup-suburb: $(this).find('select[name="pickup-suburb"]').val(),
    single-pickup-address: $(this).find('input[name="single-pickup-address"]').val()
  }
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an array in order to push a element into it. Here it is object so obviously it is not possible for you to add.

if you want to add then make it as array like

```
info.pickup.contact = [];
```

now if you add then it will accept. After adding, your array will be like follows..

```
info.pickup.contact = [];
info.pickup.contact.push("Sample");

{"pickup":{"contact":["Sample"]}}
```